# AWS Cognito User Devices Trigger

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

We use AWS Cognito for user authentication. Every user can have multiple devices. We would like to react to newly registered or deleted devices for every user. Ideally through a lambda trigger. How can we archieve that?

These standard triggers won't work for our usecase: [Customizing User Pool Workflows with Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html?icmpid=docs_cognito_console)

Does anyone have sugguestions how to tackle that problem?

Answer (score -1):

Step1: In AWS Cognito you net to enable the end-user device tracking as mentioned in the below document.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/

Step2: Every authentication attempt for the user, you can create an SNS message with the device info and user info.

Step3: Push this message into a SQS so that it can trigger a AWS Lambda

Step4: Process the message and respond to the user according to the required logic.

I hope this helps.